# Negative look-ahead assertion in list.files in R

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds

I try to list all files in a directory that do *not* start with "Camera1", but end with ".png". For doing so, I am using a regular expression in list.files in R. 
To exclude "Camera1", I tried to use a negative lookahead, but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake? ;)

```
list.files(pathToDirectory, pattern = "^(?!Camera1).*\\.png")
```

I get the error: `invalid 'pattern' regular expression`
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like the default engine doesn't like lookarounds, so you need to use Perl.  This works:

```
dat <- c("Camera1.png", "Camera2.png", "hello.png", "boo")
grep("^(?!Camera1).*\\.png", dat, value=T, perl=T)
# [1] "Camera2.png" "hello.png"
```

But this doesn't:

```
grep("^(?!Camera1).*\\.png", dat, value=T)
# invalid regular expression '(?<!Camera1)\.png', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

So, to do what you what you want:

```
grep("(?<!Camera1)\\.png", list.files(), perl=T, value=T)
```