# Matching character followed by exactly 1 digit

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to align formatting of some clinical trial IDs two merge two databases. For example, in database A patient 123 visit 1 is stored as '123v01' and in database B just '123v1'

I can match A to B by grep match those containing 'v0' and strip out the trailing zero to just 'v', but for academic interest & expanding `R` / `regex` skills, I want to reverse match B to A by matching only those containing 'v' followed by only 1 digit, so I can then separately pad that digit with a leading zero.

For a reprex:

```
string <- c("123v1", "123v01", "123v001")
```

I can match those with >= 2 digits following a 'v', then inverse subset

```
> idx <- grepl("v(\\d{2})", string)
> string[!idx]
[1] "123v1"
```

But there must be a way to match 'v' followed by just a single digit only? I have tried the lookarounds

```
# Negative look ahead "v not followed by 2+ digits"
grepl("v(?!\\d{2})", string)

# Positive look behind "single digit following v"
grepl("(?<=v)\\d{1})", string)
```

But both return an 'invalid regex' error

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not much good at regex, but I suggest `[vV][0-9]{1}[!0-9]`

Comment: what about `grepl("v\\d{1}$", string)`?

Comment: Or even shorter, as `\\d` is one digit: `grepl("v\\d$", string)`, where `$` indicates end of string. But maybe its better to remove all leading zeros e.g. with `sub("v0*", "v", string)` and then make the match.

Comment: Mind that `v(?!\d{2})` matches `vWORD_HERE` - i.e. even when no digit is there after `v`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559945/3832970) with the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grepl("v\\d(?!\\d)", string, perl=TRUE)
```

The `v\d(?!\d)` pattern matches `v`, 1 digits and then makes sure there is no digit immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. after the `v` + 1 digit).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtPkrJ/1).

Note that you need to enable PCRE regex flavor with the `perl=TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `perl=TRUE` flag on your `grepl` function.

e.g.

```
grepl("v(?!\\d{2})", string, perl=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535960/negative-look-ahead-assertion-in-list-files-in-r) for more info.

Comment: `v(?!\d{2})` matches `vWORD_HERE` - i.e. even when no digit is there after `v`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8F2iN/1) with an unexpected match.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't check whether the OP's regex's solved their problem, I just addressed the "invalid regex" error the OP mentioned.